# In Django, how can I create a independent combobox that doesn't use the database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new in world Django. In my `index.html` page, I would like to insert a simple combobox that won't be connected to the database, but will be independent, for building miscellaneous code.

There is something wrong. I don't see the combobox and the index page doesn't open. What should I write in `forms.py`, `view.py`, `models.py`, `urls.py`, `index.html` and elsewhere? Thank you all!

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = [
    ("blue", "Blue"),
    ("green", "Green"),
    ("black", "Black"),
]


class SimpleCombobox(forms.Form):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

**app1/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import SimpleCombobox #Creato per Combobox


def app1(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html')


def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SimpleCombobox(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            # Output Sample
            # {'favorite_colors': ['blue', 'green']}
            return redirect("index")

    else:
        form = SimpleCombobox()

    return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
```

**app1/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from app1.views import index #Aggiunto per combobox

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.app1),
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

**index.html**

```
...
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit">
            submit
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
...
```

**mysite (project)/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')), #si occuperà di gestire tutti i link dell'app app1
    path('', include('app1.urls')) #Aggiunto per Combobox
]
```

**settings.py**

I also tried not to put it, so I also tried to leave `'DIRS': []` by default: the page still opens without problems

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / 'templates' ],
        ...
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is okay. If you are not going to persist data then you do not need to use Django `models`. The only thing you need to do is create a instance of this form and render it.

Suppose we [`create and app`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#startapp) called `myapp`. There you have your files, such as `forms`, `views`, `urls`, etc.

myapp/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from myapp.forms import SimpleCombobox

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SimpleCombobox(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            # Output Sample
            # {'favorite_colors': ['blue', 'green']}
            return redirect("index")

    else:
        form = SimpleCombobox()

    return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
```

myapp/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index')
]
```

Note that you can also use [`relative imports`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) (e.g. `from .forms import SimpleCombobox`). Although in my example I am using absolute imports.

index.html

```
...
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit">
            submit
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
...
```

Then [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) `myapp.urls` setup to the root `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

If you have setup your templates correctly at `settings.py` (for instance):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / 'templates' ],
        ...
    },
]
```

And have a running server, you should be good to go!

Comment: I've been studying Django for a week. Intensive study though. I know what you're talking about, but to be safe can you also write me about how to set URLS and how to write import? I am afraid of making a mistake. I will be happy to accept your answer, thank you

Comment: I have added a little more code and explanation about it all. Glad to help!

Comment: There is a problem. I did everything you wrote. I can open the page correctly, but there is no combobox. Only the Submit button is present, but the combobox is not present. For what reason? Anyway you are kind, thanks in advance

Comment: That is odd, it should display three boxes for colors. But, if it is not rendering means that there is no `form` to be found. Thus, in `views.py` where you create a instance of it, check the form (a simple `.print` suffices). Note that I omitted `forms.py` in my answer, because your file is correct :)

Comment: I've updated my question by putting the code I use in the py files. It's the same as what you suggested. The only difference is that I open both the site at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and both at http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1 (although I would only need it on 127.0.0.1:8000). In both cases there is no combobox. What am I doing wrong with your code?

Comment: Remove `path('', views.app1),` from `app1/urls.py`. This path is pointing to `app1` `view` that has no context (the 3rd param  in `render` where we send the form in `index`). So there is no `form` to render in your template. What is happening is that Django will use the first matching URL, so it just ignores your second path which is the right one (index).

Comment: I tried, but I get an error. No page opens and I get the error. Why? Maybe mysite(project)/urls.py has something to do with it too? (you can see in the code I updated earlier). Thank you

Comment: Yes, my last answer was based on your update. Although they are duplicate your root urls.py is fine. Could you be more specific about the error?

Comment: Since I didn't know which error to report to you, I took the screenshot and uploaded it to imgbb: https://ibb.co/GJCGMPn

Comment: As far as I understand, maybe, the problem is that index.html, therefore the template, is not found. It is located in app1/templates/app1/index.html. In settings.py, in TEMPLATES, I tried to write your 'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR / 'templates' ] or even 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/app1')]. The page does not open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254110/discussion-between-niko-and-folidex23).